# Answered questions in unanswered list

Tags: discussion, feature-request, unanswered-questions

I sometimes read old questions in unanswered list to see if there're missing ones I can help. But a frequent situation is many questions has been answered perfectly while the OP doesn't accept as an answer. I'm sure about this because OP commented on answer with "Wow", "Great", "Thank you very much" etc. It is usually seen in groups of new or inactive users. The same phenomenon occurs on those whose answer is rather easy and simple as well as duplicated so that problems have been solved in comment, even not necessary for a formal answer. I wish some ways to put out these kinds of questions in unanswered list.

Comment: There is an "answer crusade" chat thread that requests votes for those answers, which at some number of votes (1?) removes the question from the unanswered list.

Comment: Then you would love the Crusade of Answers chatroom! That's the entire purpose of that room. Hope to see you there sometime!

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you. I feel we have many common interests. Could you leave me a mail for contact? I would delete the post immediately.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang I'd like to chat, but first let's talk at the Crusade of Answers. Let me know if you have trouble using the chat rooms here.

Comment: @rschwieb I've been there.

Answer (score 3):

Not to leave *this* question unanswered...

1. The SE definition of "answered" is the presence of an answer that is *either* accepted *or* has positive score. This is explained in Jeff Atwood's post [OK, Now Define “Answered”](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/). Thus, in many cases a single click of upvote arrow will put the question out of the unanswered list.  There's a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/119994/zero-score-answers-to-unanswered-questions-by-tag) that brings you questions with answers in need of votes,  filtered by tag.
2. In (rare) cases where a correct answer has *negative* score, you may be able to change  it to positive with help of [Crusaders](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers).
3. If an answer is hiding in comments, you can ask the comment author to re-post;   failing that, post an answer yourself (possibly as *community wiki*). The Crusaders may help the answer   get positive score.
4. Further reading: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9877/, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8583/
5. Last but not least... congratulations/condolences on becoming the 14th [Unsung Hero](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero) of Math.SE. Votes are scarce around here. (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11640/)

Comment: Yeah, I'm also confused with that wired medal. Is that good or bad? What do you think it suggests?

Comment: @ShuchangZhang It suggests that you answered many questions that were not drawing much attention. This is a commendable effort. It is not rewarded enough with upvotes, but the system is trying to compensate for it by giving you a gold badge. (I just got `Tenacious` badge myself, which is the silver-level version of `Unsung Hero`.)

Comment: I think there may be other implications. Either those questions are so naive that luckily, I was the first to answer and meanwhile accepted, or the answer's too technical to be readable for others. It's not been more than 3 days to obtain Unsung Hero after I got Tenacious badge.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang Same here: I became the 15th Unsung Hero today. This gold badge has become too easy to get.

Comment: LOL. Cong, too.